# I am not able to pass data to another html page using js node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[screenshot of receipt page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B4dY.png)
When I click the submit button the data doesn't pass to receipt html file. The receipt page is showing but the name is not showing.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var myApp = express();

myApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

myApp.use(bodyParser.json());

var myApp = express();
myApp.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
myApp.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
myApp.set('view engine','ejs');
myApp.use(express.json()); 

myApp.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('purchase');
});

myApp.get('/printReceipt',function(req,res){
    res.render('purchase')
});

myApp.post('/printReceipt', (req,res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
res.render('receipt', {
        name: name,
});
});
```

purchase ejs file

```
//purchase.ejs
<form  method="POST" action="/printReceipt">
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="checkName()"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></td>
</form>
```

receipt ejs file

```
//receipt.ejs
<tr align="center">
<td>Name:</td>
   <td>:</td>
<td align="right"><%= name %></td>
```

Comment: How is the form submitted?

Comment: @Evert <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >

Answer (score 0):

U need to check your purchase.ejs file.

Check the form where you have Method, action,  u should also add the enctype, which is the content type.